# Is it good practice to validate IDs in a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have a HMT association setup between my `Artist` and `Group` models:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artist_groups, through: :artist_groups
end

class ArtistGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships, class_name: "ArtistGroupMembership", dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :group

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates_presence_of :artist_id, :group_id
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artist_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :artist_groups, source: :artist
end
```

As you'll notice in my `ArtistGroup` join model it validates to make sure the an artist and group are present.

When the association is saved, whether I do something like this:

```
 artist.groups.push(Group.first)
```

or create a form in my view (sans ID inputs) ActiveRecord is smart enough to map the association. With this in my should I even be validating these IDs in my join models? I notice this becomes even more of a pain when dealing with polymorphic associations.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 automatically requires that the `belongs_to :artist` refers to an existing `artist` so having extra validation is completely unnecessary. You can make that requirement optional by doing

```
belongs_to :artist, optional: true
```